# Weird c++ variable declaration error, says a class is a private member of itself

Tags: c++

I'm working on a parser to build abstract syntax trees.

I've got this Node base class for all my nodes.

```
// Base for all nodes
class Node {
  public:
    virtual ~Node();
    virtual int position() = 0; // code string index of first character associated with this Node
    virtual int end() = 0; // code string index of first immediately after the last character associated with this Node
};
```

One of the subclasses is an expression node:

```
// Expression node
class ExpressionNode: Node {
  public:
    virtual ~ExpressionNode();
    virtual int position() = 0;
    virtual int end() = 0;
};
```

And one of its subclasses is an identifier node, where I get a very strange error on one of the members:

```
// Identifier Expression
class IdentNode: ExpressionNode {
  public:
    int namePosition;
    std::string name;

    Node *n; // Error - 'Node' is a private member of 'Node'

    IdentNode();
    ~IdentNode();

    virtual int position();
    virtual int end();
};
```

Why would I get this error? I am honestly baffled.

Comment: Tried `class IdentNode: public ExpressionNode {` already?

Comment: Just a question: Did you intend for `ExpressionNode` to derive from `Node`?

Comment: Whoops, it does in my code just didn't type that in here, edited to reflect

Comment: Is this ALL OF YOUR CODE? I just entered it in Visual Studio and it built fine. Everything checks out fine. So, not sure why would you get an error like that.

Comment: @MichaelTaufen Actually I believe the error says that the **class constructor** is a private member. Read the error message thoroughly again.

Comment: I copied and pasted the error message. It seems your compiler is more informative than mine haha.

@armanali Maybe you have different build flags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(I'm assuming that you intended ExpressionNode to derive from Node.) By default, inheritance is `private`, which means that base class members are not accessible to derived classes. Use `protected` (members are accessible by derived, but not other scopes) or `public` inheritance (all public members in base are accessible everywhere).

```
class ExpressionNode : public Node {
...
class IdentNode : public ExpressionNode {
```

Comment: What is he inheriting in this example?

Comment: Though, given that, even if ExpressionNode does not publicly inherit from Node, it can still point to objects of class Node. Is there a reason this error only seems to occur after two levels of inheritance?

@black, I will accept as soon as it lets me, 2 minutes left on the clock.

Comment: @MichaelTaufen:  would guess that it has to do with how names are looked up. I need to run, but maybe I'll investigate more later.